# Conseguir objeto de un array proporcionando un atributo del objeto

Tags: javascript, array, object

Tengo un array de objetos como el siguiente:

```
var nicknames = []

nicknames.push( {id:"100", name:"Juan"} , {id:"200", name:"Mateo"} );
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de uno de los objetos del array `nicknames` suministrándole el nombre o el ID de dicho objeto?

---

**Pregunta original:** [Javascript get corresponding key/value from object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27741114/4359029)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existe una solución muy sencilla para eso, se trata del método `filter` disponible de forma nativa en todos los arrays [Referencia en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter):

```
var results = nicknames.filter(function (nickname) { return nickname.id == '200'; });
var firstObj = (results.length > 0) ? results[0] : null;
```

#### Nota:

El método `filter` devuelve un array con todos para los elementos que se cumple la condición, con lo que se ha de comtemplar que no exista el elemento o que existan varios.

Answer (score 7):

Tomando en cuenta que tenemos la variable de la siguiente forma:

```
var nicknames= [
    {id:"100", nickname:"Juan"},
    {id:"200", nickname:"Mateo"}
];
```

---

### Solución 1 - Nativo Js

A través del uso `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
/**
 * Devolverá un arreglo con el objeto a buscar o uno vacio si no lo encuentra.
 */
var nickname = nicknames.filter(function(nickname) {
    return nickname.id === "100";
});
```

A través del uso `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
/**
 * Devolverá el arreglo requerido o null si no lo encuentra.
 */
var nickname = nicknames.reduce(function(value, nickname) {
    return nickname.id === "100" ? nickname : null;
}, null);
```

---

### Solución 2 - Uso de prototype

Otro método es y el cual a mi me gusta mucho, es el uso de prototype. Quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
/**
 * Devolverá el objeto que coincida con la llave-valor indicados como
 * argumentos de la función.
 *
 * @param String column    El nombre de la columna o llave de referencia
 * @param Any value        El valor buscado sobre la columna indicada
 * @return [Object|Null]   Devolverá null en caso de no hallar coincidencia, en caso contrario devolverá el objeto coincidente
 */
Array.prototype.findBy = function (column, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        var object = this[i];
        if (column in object && object[column] === value) {
            return object;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

El ejemplo de uso quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var nickname = nicknames.findBy('id', '100');
```

---

### Solución 3 - Uso de librerías

Puedes utilizar una librería como [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) que te brinde herramientas como esas para un filtrado de datos. Ejemplo:

```
var nickname = _.findWhere(nicknames, {id: "100"});
```

[Documentación oficial de _.findeWhere()](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) (en inglés)

Answer (score 3):

**ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)** provee la función [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
function buscar_item_por_id(id){

    return items.find(function(item){
        return item.id === id;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya mencionó [Jorge Pastrano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/556/20) la forma más fácil y nativa de hacer una selección sobre el arreglo es usando la función `filter`:

```
var resultados = nicknames.filter(function (nickname) {
    //return {expresion booleana},
});
```

Donde `{expresión booleana}` puede ser una comparación con la propiedad `id` o `name` según lo necesites

`resultados` queda asignado con un nuevo arreglo solo con los objetos filtrados.

Sin embargo para navegadores que no soporten esta función (por ejemplo IE8 o menor) se puede usar el siguiente polyfill (extraido de la [documentación de `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter))

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
        'use strict';

        if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var res = [];
        var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in t) {
                var val = t[i];

                // NOTE: Technically this should Object.defineProperty at
                //       the next index, as push can be affected by
                //       properties on Object.prototype and Array.prototype.
                //       But that method's new, and collisions should be
                //       rare, so use the more-compatible alternative.
                if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
                    res.push(val);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```